# Good asymptotic for this recursion?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations, functional-equations

Consider some initial integer values and let the integer sequence continue like

$$\begin{align}f(n) &= f(n-1) \\
&+ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5) f(n-2) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)}{2} f(n-3) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)}{3} f(n-4) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots (n+5)}{6} f(n-5) \\
&+ K.
\end{align}$$

For some positive integer $K$.

Consider the cases where eventually the sequence remains strictly increasing.

What are possible closed forms if any ?

What are the best asymptotics !?

I assume the best(?) asymptotics are something like

$ A ( n ! )^6 $ or $ A ( n!)^5 $ ? 
( $ A $ some constant )
Big those estimates seem poor and even kinda ignore the variable $K$.

So i doubt my own guesses.

Not sure how to handle it.

Reminder me of the factorial of hypergeo.

Clearly this is just part of a bigger question ; the similar recursion equations

$$ \sum_i p_i(n) f(n-i) = 0 $$

And perhaps it is useful to think of the related equations

$$ \sum_i p_i(x) f(x/i) = 0 $$

$$ \sum_i p_i(x) f(x/2^i) = 0 $$

And look at their Taylor series solutions ?
Those solutions might be found and understood by systems of equations ...

Comment: As the function will start growing very fast, we roughly have $f(n) \approx (n·(n + 1)·(n + 2)·(n + 3)·(n + 4)·(n + 5))·f(n - 2)$, and therefore $f(n) \in O((n+5)!^3)$

Comment: That needs to be proven formally Sudix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumptions that $f$ is positive and strictly increasing we have:
$$
\begin{align}f(n) &= f(n-1) \\
&+ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5) f(n-2) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)}{2} f(n-3) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)}{3} f(n-4) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots (n+5)}{6} f(n-5) \\
&+ K.
\\&\Leftrightarrow\\
f(n)&=f(n-2) \\
&+ (n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+6) f(n-3) \\
&- \frac{ (n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+6)}{2} f(n-4) \\
&- \frac{ (n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+6)}{3} f(n-5) \\
&- \frac{ (n+1)(n+2)\dots (n+6)}{6} f(n-6) \\
&+ K\\
&+ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5) f(n-2) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)}{2} f(n-3) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)}{3} f(n-4) \\
&- \frac{ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots (n+5)}{6} f(n-5) \\
&+ K\\
&\le f(n-2) \\
&+ (n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+6) f(n-3) \\
&+ n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5) f(n-2) \\
&+ 2K\\
&=  \\
&+ (n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+6) f(n-3) \\
&+ (1+n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)) f(n-2) \\
&+ 2K
\end{align}$$
Further we have then
$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &\le\\
&+ (n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+6) f(n-3) \\
&+ (1+n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)) f(n-2) \\
&+ 2K\\
&\le \\
&+ 2(1+n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)) f(n-2) \\
&+ 2K
\end{align}
$$
For all $n\ge N$ for some $N$ we further have:
$$
f(n)\le 
 c\cdot 2(1+n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+5)) f(n-2) 
$$

You then can solve this recurrence equation, e.g. [per WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29%20%3Dc*2*%28%28n%2B1%29%5E2%28n%2B2%29%28n%2B3%29%28n%2B4%29%28n%2B5%29%29%20f%28n-2%29) and obtain some bounds using it (you can get an even better than I initially guessed).

Comment: I have given +1. You gave a formal upper bound. But no lower or sharp asymptotic. On the other hand your tricks might be used to achieve that. I can imagine. How about hope for a closed form ? Do you even believe in it ? Thank you.

Comment: I doubt that, without intense efforts, a better upper bound (one that shows in $\mathcal O$-notation) can be achieved, nevertheless a sharp bound. Regarding the closed form: The recursion formula very straightforwardly leads to a differential equation of degree 5, so (while I am not proficient on ODE) I doubt traditional methods will lead to an answer, and I wouldn't be surprised at all if there was no closed form for this particular recurrence equation.